# How to configure antd style in webpack4.0

Tags: webpack, antd

I've building a scaffolding use webpack4.0+react+mobx+antd, but i don't know how to configure the antd style. antd component already render, but no style...

if i use older config like

`["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": "css" }]`

webpackdevserver will throw error

`Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.plugins[1] should be one of these:
   object { apply, ... } | function
   -> Plugin of type object or instanceof Function
   Details:
    * configuration.plugins[1] misses the property 'apply'.
      function
      -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
    * configuration.plugins[1] misses the property 'apply'.
      function
      -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
    * configuration.plugins[1] should be an instance of function
      -> Function acting as plugin`

Comment: I suggest including the error you receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its my linking error, just link the less-loader